# Looking for USB flash drive with its Removable Media Bit set

Tags: usb, hard-disk, data-storage, windows, flash-drive

Windows specifically has this annoying issue where it will not allow multiple partitions on a USB flash drive.  If you create multiple partitions, Windows will only see the first one.  Linux doesn't care, MacOS doesn't care; only Windows cares.

*Some* flash drives, however, have their Removable Media Bit set, in which case Windows sees them as a removable hard drive and will work with as many partitions as you see fit to create.  I need one of these drives.  Unfortunately, this isn't a feature that gets advertised at all.

My efforts to Google this feature only comes up with a bunch of posts from people trying to set this feature on drives they already have (which usually involve shady hack tools from Chinese or Russian web sites).  Lexar is the only manufacturer that publishes a tool to set this bit on their drives, but it's old and it only works on some models.

I once bought a SanDisk Cruzer drive that had it set but at the time I didn't care about the feature.  I've bought SanDisk drives since then that don't have it, and that one drive is too small (16GB).

Microsoft has a published list of their "Windows-to-Go" certified flash drives (which all have their RMBs set because Windows-To-Go requires it), but all of these flash drive are ridiculously expensive because of the certification.  I don't care about Windows-To-Go anyway.  I just need a drive that I can create at least 3 partitions on.

Does anybody know for certain a particular make/model of flash drive that has this bit set?  I'd like it to be at least 128GB, but I'd settle for a 64GB model if that's all there is.

Comment: Unless I'm confused, [SanDisk makes the Cruzer Glide in a 128GB](http://a.co/eaj2o4Q) (though I haven't confirmed it has the bit flipped like my 8GB one.) The major downside I see is that it's USB 2.0.

Comment: @JMY1000 Yeah USB 2.0 is a deal-breaker for me. I'm going to be booting off it and USB2 would kill that.